# Login script not working, displaying echo message

Tags: php, mysql

I have a login script written in PHP. If the username or password is incorrect, it will echo 'Username or password is invalid', which is currently what's happening (even though the username and password is correct)

Here's my PHP code:

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","dbuser","dbpass","dbname");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $password);

$logincheck = mysqli_connect($con, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'");
$result = mysqli_query($con, $logincheck);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count == 1){
$_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
header('Location: index.php');
}else{
echo "Username or password is invalid.";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Do an `echo "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";`. Copy and paste the result of that line directly into MySQL. Does it give it a result then? What errors does it give if any?

Comment: Odd, can you just `echo $username;` and `echo $password;` right after you assign those variables from `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['password']` respectively. Does it output what you expected?

Comment: You're not going live with this, *right?*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some error in fetching data and may be use forgot to use md5 if password is encrypted so make sure first

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $username);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $password);

    $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
    {
        $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Username or password is invalid.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Do you mind letting me  know what the problem with my script was?

Comment: You are using mysqli_connect for execute query. you have to use mysqli_query

Comment: @PareshGami Why are you suggesting the OP to use MD5?

Comment: it is encryption technique i am suggest to use it

Comment: Well it isn't safe anymore to use as a password storage function, so please don't suggest it anymore, not in this century. Maybe in 1993/95 but not today. Either PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function or the compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/ - In suggesting MD5 and for future answers you may give, might attract downvotes, and/or (more) criticism.